# Insertion of classless divs messes up css .class:nth-of-type(n):before indexing

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have list items that are indexed by css `:before` using `:nth-of-type` ...

```
#list .item:nth-of-type(1):before{content:"1";}
#list .item:nth-of-type(2):before{content:"2";}
```

The problem is I am using a smooth scroller addon which will insert extra divs in a scrollable area in order to achieve its "bouncy-edge" effects. The inserted divs are not of class `.item` but the insert will mess up the css indexing none-the-less.

This is puzzling since I do not understand why the `:nth-of-type` should care about those divs, but the result is the index is off by the number of divs it inserts (2) but the inserted divs have no `:before` content assigned to them -- so it seems I need a 'refresh' or something.

Testing on Chrome.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E5KW/1/)

Comment: `:nth-of-type()` cares about those divs *because they are divs*. The word "type" refers to element type, represented in HTML as the tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how `nth-of-type` works, it works properly only for types (tag), not for classes. So when you use this:

```
#list .item:nth-of-type(1):before{content:"1";}
```

It in fact checks if the first child has class `item`, if it does, insert the `:before`, otherwise it does nothing, the same for other rules. So when you use this code:

```
$('#outer').prepend('<div/><div>');
```

it in fact inserts **2 divs** (not 1 div), it's because you might mistype the tags, it might be `<div></div>` (not `<div/><div>`). So the HTML code becomes:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Because the first 2 divs do not have class `item`, the first 2 rules are ignored, starting from the third rule, we have:

```
#list .item:nth-of-type(3):before{content:"c";}
```

from now the rules work but it applies from the third div, hence you get the result:

```
c 1
d 2
...
6 h
7
8
```

The last 2 items `7` and `8` do not have `:before` inserted because there is not any rule targeting them.

If you want to just produce the correct result you want, you can try using CSS counter like this:

```
#outer{
  height:80px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  /* add this */
  counter-reset:alpha;
}
#outer .item {
  counter-increment:alpha;
}
#outer .item:before{
  content:counter(alpha,lower-alpha);
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5E5KW/2/)